# in my url the index.php path appears

Tags: url, http-status-403, index.php

my current path `

> http://magento2/index.php/router/controller/action

### preface

- this address (index.php) is added to the line after the redirect, but there is no error
- I didn't do anything to make it happen. In an instant, it just happened and I don't know how to remove it.
- I already had this once. it was solved by reinstalling magento2
- I didn't change anything in nginx config
- .htaccess in /var/www/magento2/app/

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all denied
</IfVersion>
```

- .htaccess in /var/www/magento2/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

- NGINX config /etc/nginx/config-enable/file:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
         server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

     server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80;

         server_name  magento2 magento2.com www.magento2.com;
         index  index.php;

         set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
         set $MAGE_MODE developer;

         access_log /var/log/nginx/magento2.com-access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/magento2.com-error.log;

         include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
     }
```

Comment: please let me know if you need any more information! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article.

https://www.milople.com/blogs/remove-index-php-from-url-magento/

Answer (score 0):

****i do it that**
**- `it helped me to reinstall admin data`****

bin/magento setup:install 
--base-url=http://magento2/ 
--db-host=localhost 
--db-name=magento2 
--db-user=esca7a 
--db-password=5800 
--admin-firstname=admin 
--admin-lastname=admin 
--admin-email=admin@admin.com 
--admin-user=admin 
--admin-password=admin123 
--language=en_US 
--currency=USD 
--timezone=Europe/Minsk 
--use-rewrites=1 
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 
--elasticsearch-port=9200 
--elasticsearch-timeout=30

***I hope this helps you as it helped me***